# Refreshing an activity started with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application with a couple of activities which contains several fragments each. There is a syncing service in the background which causes the activities to refresh with

```
Intent refreshIntent = getIntent();
refreshIntent.putExtra("message", Globals.MSG_DATA_UPDATE);
finish();
startActivity(refreshIntent);
```

because that is the simplest way to refresh all the underlying fragments at once when the data set has changed. I use the extra to determine which result has to be set if the activity finally returns to the calling one.

The problem ist just that this refreshing breaks the startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() in a way that the requestCode is preserved, but the resultCode and Intent are always null (I tried all the variants proposed for "onActivityResult: Intent is always null" here)

One possible, but very unpractical solution is to refresh all the fragments (i am using a fragment pager here) instead of the activity but it would be a whole lot easier if that is avoidable, especially because the fragments and the pager adapt to the data in onCreate() and I would have to cancel everything and rerun that code.

I need to return the intent back to the calling activity because these need to refresh too when the data set has changed and the only way is with an Intent extra or an resultCode. So is there any possibility to refresh the activity without breaking the returning of the result?

Comment: Note that this doesn't "refresh" the current activity instance in the way you think. Instead, it creates a new activity instance.

Comment: If you are in an activity at the moment of refreshing does it create another instance of this one? since it doesn't look like you are finishing the currently running one, that could be causing the trouble.

Comment: i call finish() on the running instance before starting a new one, that was a proposed solution here to the refreshing problem. Or is there an alternative to recreate the acitivity instance, which then would solve the problem?

Comment: recreate() also creates a new instance. The screen rotation does essentially call onCreate() again, but with savedInstanceState and that doesn't break the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer myself.

```
Recreate()
```

This does multiple things instead of the finish() - startActivity commands suggested for refreshing:

- it doesn't break the link to startActivityForResult()
- it reacts like a redraw after screen rotation, so you can save information into *savedInstanceState* which you have to implement anyway